# finding a character in a string

Tags: python

> Используйте цикл `for` для прохождения строки, и подсчитайте число символов `l` в строке `Hello world`.

Это моя программа на Питоне и она не работает. Прошу вас показать мне правильный подход и почему мой код не работает:

```
str = 'Hello world'
k = 0
for i in str: 
    if str[b] == 'l':
      k += 1

print(k)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if str[b] == 'l':
```

В вашей программе нет переменной `b`, потому ошибка.

Используйте прямо переменную `i` из заголовка цикла

```
for i in str: 
    if i == 'l':
```

так как ее значением является очередной символ из переменной `str`.

---

*Примечание 1:*

Есть тоже такая возможность поправки:

```
for b in range(len(str)): 
    if str[b] == 'l':
```

но это некрасивый, не Питонический подход.

*Примечание 2:*

`str` не очень удобное имя для переменной, потому что оно есть имением встроенной функции. Было бы хорошо применить какое-то другое, по меньшей мере `str_`.

Answer (score 2):

Задавать вопросы принято по-русски, но вот ответ / It is customary to ask questions in Russian, but here is the answer:

```
str = 'Hello world' 
k = 0 
for i in str: 
    if i == 'l': 
        k += 1
print(k)
```